# Springboot - DB driven testing, CRUD ONLY on test classes

Tags: spring-boot

I have a few tests (Springboot) which needs a DB connection (SQL Server) to read data and persist. The application itself does not require a DB connection. (Its almost like an integration test.)

What will be the best method to set this up?

AFAIK this is not a "mock object", these are database driven tests --- meaning all the data for the test cases will be read from DB tables, asserted/compared and then persisted. Hence the question.

Thanking you.

Comment: Does it need to be SQL Server? Would another relational database work for it?

Comment: @Gabriel Yes, it has to be SQL server.

Comment: I do not understand... Why would you need those integration tests on an application that does not use a database? Can you give some more details?

Comment: Its a decision from the project architect. The plan is to have tests run during deployment and there is a historical record of tests/results etc. The challenge is to set up integration tests to use a database driven approach. In a way the term "integration tests" is a misnomer.